# Is there a way to make XSLT throw an error if an attribute or element does not exist?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for an easy way to make XSLT throw an error when I try to access an attribute (or element) in the source XML that does not exist.
Currently what I do is first check if an attribute exists and throw an error manually if it does not - e.g.:

```
<xsl:if test="not(attribute_to_use)">

 <xsl:message terminate="yes">

  <xsl:text>error message</xsl:text>                    

 </xsl:message>

</xsl:if>

<!-- do something -->

<xsl:attribute name="new_attribute"><xsl:value-of select="attribute_to_use" /></xsl:attribute>
```

I find that a lot of code to check for an attribute - especially if you do this for all attributes.
Is there any other way to do this within XSLT - for instance by setting a directive like "abort on non existing attributes"?

I know that one way to do this is also to use a DTD or a schemaand I will do it this way if there is no direct XSLT way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 1.0 as you would know is based on templates to match nodes, so you could write a template for matching all elements which do not have an specific attribute.

For example, the following template would match all elements such as do not have an @id attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(@id)]">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Attribute @id does not exist in element ', name())" />
    </xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

So if you want to impose that certain elements have specific attributes you could use in the match expression something like: Element[not(@id)]|Element2[not(@a)], etc. And then write a different template for each element to process them in case they have those attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="Element[not(@id)]|Element2[not(@a)]">
     <!-- Throw error message -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element">
     <!-- Process Elements which have an @id attribute -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element2">
     <!-- Process Elements which have an @a attribute -->
</xsl:template>
```

You could write templates as complicated as you need (which should not be very complicated) to throw an error when certain elements have certain properties like 'having an attribute', 'the value of an attribute is invalid', 'number of children is 5', etc.

Hope that gave you an idea of how to implement in a general way what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0, whenever you want to use a node $N and fail if it doesn't exist, just wrap the reference to $N in a function call exactly-one($N) or one-or-more($N).